# What are alternatives to update/delete records with a key that references multiple tables?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I was reading over some threads in SO, and found out that the example Party table below is incorrect because I have a foreign key referencing two tables which you cannot do. I thought the whole idea of foreign keys was to make sure that if you update or delete in one table, any row that references a foreign key gets updated or deleted. Doesn't the whole idea of limiting a foreign key to reference only a single table kind of kill that idea? What is a way to update/delete all records among all tables when you delete a key that is referenced in other tables?

In my mobile app right now, if a "party" is deleted or renamed, then I basically write a query to check all the appropriate tables and do a DELETE FROM table, WHERE condition wherever I need to. Is this the "normal" way? I thought ON DELETE CASCADE or ON UPDATE CASCADE would do the trick, but if it's only for a single referenced table, then I might as well do it by doing a query on each appropriate table.

I guess another question might be, if I have a foreign key in multiple tables, is that a sign of bad design? Is a foreign key in multiple tables supposed to be a rare occurrence?

```
CREATE TABLE Party (
      partyName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
      pcName    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (partyName, pcName),
      FOREIGN KEY (partyName, pcName) REFERENCES PC_BASIC (partyName, pcName) ON DELETE CASCADE,
      FOREIGN KEY (partyName, pcName) REFERENCES PC_STATS (partyName, pcName) ON DELETE CASCADE
      );

    CREATE TABLE PC_BASIC (
      partyName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
      pcName    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
      init      INTEGER NOT NULL,
      ac        INTEGER NOT NULL
      PRIMARY KEY (partyName, pcName)
    );

    CREATE TABLE PC_STATS (
      str integer not null,
      dex integer not null,
      partyName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
      pcName varchar(30) not null,
      PRIMARY KEY (partyName, pcName)
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *in this case* it probably indicates there is a problem with your relational schema design.

All three of your tables use the same primary key.  I would expect one of the tables to be the "master" or most important table for whatever is represented by the *combination* of `(partyName, pcName)`.  The other two tables may contain supplemental, or perhaps *optional* information, related to the master table.  If so, those two supplemental tables could each have a *single* foreign key to the *master* table only.

If that doesn't describe how your data for these tables is actually related in your business case, then please provide more details.  For instance, if the data from all three tables is required in all cases, then another option is to combine all three into a single table.

It is *not always* a design issue to have multiple foreign keys to different tables, but in those cases the foreign keys will involve a different set of columns.

Comment: Thanks, Price. I totally did not think of the case of the tables containing optional information referencing a single foreign key to the master table.